# Why does the Material FAB not change colors when disabled?

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I am disabling the Material Floating Action button but the color does not change when disabled is set to true. I thought Material has a theme for FAB's and when disabled it should turn light grey. I do not want to add code to change the background every time it is enabled/disabled.

I am currently on material version: 1.1.0

In the code I just set the fab to disabled by `fab.isEnabled = false`

Here is the xml

```
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/save_reservation_fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/keyline_2"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save_black_72dp"
                app:tint="@color/color_on_primary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

This is what the disabled/enabled fab looks like:

[image]

It should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I *suspect* that this is the culprit:

> ```
> app:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"
> ```

This is going to tint the color of your FAB regardless of its state.

You could solve this by setting the tint to a `ColorStateList` instead of a raw color value. That is, create a file named `fab_color.xml` in your `res/color/` directory, and include this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="your gray here"/>
    <item android:color="@color/color_primary"/>
</selector>
```

And change your tint to this instead:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_color"
```

Alternatively, you could adjust your Activity's theme such that the default color of the FAB is the color you want (`@color/color_primary`) and then remove the `app:backgroundTint` attr altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The version `1.2.0` [introduced](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/94cd734a5100b4a693d3bf88a6019f4d810089d2#diff-2b09bd518e204efd7f5f214c3981c2fe) the support for enabled/disabled states in the `FloatingActionButton`.

Now the default style support the disabled state and the [background color](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/color/mtrl_fab_bg_color_selector.xml) is based on the `colorOnSurface` when disabled:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorSecondary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image][image]

You can change it using the `app:backgroundTint` attribute with a custom selector or using:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Custom.FloatingActionButton"
      ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Custom.FloatingActionButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Strangely on the material website, there is no disabled state being shown, so I supposed this was not supported.