# how to grey out floatingActionButton to indicate disabled state?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I have a `FloatingActionButton` in a android layout.

by Code I try to disable the button as follow:

```
if(notAvailable){
    floatingActionButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

This makes the button unclickable, but it looks like it would be still active.

How to indicate (grey out), that the button is diabled ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change FAB background color when disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342098/change-fab-background-color-when-disabled)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63429217/2016562

Comment: The version 1.2.0 introduced the support for enabled/disabled states in the `FloatingActionButton`.
Now the **default style** supports the disabled state and the background color is based on the `colorOnSurface` when disabled (with `0.12` alpha)

Answer (score 0):

Use css to edit the button style.
For eg:
.class
{ color: lightgrey; }

Comment: The question is related to Android

Comment: Should have removed `material-ui` tag. it's a React library

Comment: Material UI is many things...